# Get current week, month and year records using SQL

Tags: php, mysql, get, range

I have a table having a column which has values like **2017-08-21**

See the screencast [here](https://www.screencast.com/t/GVWVOmpvz).

Now I need to get the values of current week, current month and current year.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Mysql or MSSQL?  Pls post what have you tried so far too.  Give a look to date functions (mssql or mysql) before.

Comment: What do you mean by get values? Are you summing some columns by week,month,year or just listing the rows on a where condition?

Comment: MS SQL - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql

Comment: @ P.Salmon  i just need to select the entries for current week , month and year.

Comment: `WHERE 'hitdate' >= $first_date & 'hitdate' <= $last_date` ?

Comment: to start with, what is the datatype of your column ?

Comment: @THOMAS  its a date type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current week :

```
SELECT * 
FROM  your_table 
WHERE YEARWEEK(`your_date`) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE())
```

Current month

```
SELECT * 
FROM  your_table 
WHERE YEAR(`your_date`) = YEAR(CURDATE())
  AND MONTH(`your_date`) = MONTH(CURDATE())
```

Current year

```
SELECT * 
FROM  your_table 
WHERE YEAR(`your_date`) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

To select all records in current year

```
Select *
FROM `table_name`
WHERE YEAR('hit_date') = YEAR(CURDATE());
```

To select all records in current month

```
Select *
FROM `table_name`
WHERE MONTH('hit_date') = MONTH(CURDATE())
AND YEAR('hit_date') = YEAR(CURDATE());
```

To select all records in current week

```
Select *
FROM `table_name`
WHERE YEARWEEK('hit_date') = YEARWEEK(CURDATE());
```

Please note regarding YEARWEEK you can specify your week start day depend on mode ( second parameter ) please have a look [MySQL YEARWEEK() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/func_mysql_yearweek.asp)